# SetAlignment method in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

1) When I run it, all the objects placed in the TOP_CENTER
as you can see in the code I tried to place the button in the BOTTOM_RIGHT and it didn't work.

2) Can a `Scene` include two layouts? (Two `VBox`-es for example).

```
public void NewQuestion ()
{
    sum++;
    t=new Text("Question number: "+sum);

    textfield=new TextField();
    pane = new VBox();

    Button NextQuestion = new Button ("Next Question");
    NextQuestion.setOnAction(e-> NextQuestionButtonClicked(e));
    pane.getChildren().addAll(t, textfield, NextQuestion);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    NextQuestion.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);//<---


    Scene mainscene = new Scene(pane,420, 530);


    Qstage.setScene(mainscene);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your second question first : each layout is a node so you can make a Hbox and then add 2 Vboxs to it and in a similar fashion have all combinations of it. since each button is also a node, you can add a Vbox and a button to an Hbox to position them horizontally with respect to each other

Now back to your first question:
Here is a list and an example with Pos.CENTER and Pos.CENTER_LEFT :
[image]

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any more questions about this

Comment: also accept my answer if it helped you and i feel kgeorgiy has given you some wrong information

Answer (score 4):

1) `button.setAlignment` sets how the text and icons are places *inside* the button ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setAlignment-javafx.geometry.Pos-)). To align the `button` within a `pane` you should apply desired alignment to the `pane` itself. In you case:

```
pane.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
```

instead of

```
pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
```

2) The `Scene` should have a single `root`. But the `root` itself may be a `VBox` or `HBox` and you could put multiple boxes inside other box.

Comment: i want to place only the button in the BOTTOM_RIGHT and the rest i want to place in the TOP_CENTER

Comment: In this case you need a [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) and place main content to the center, and the button to the bottom.

Comment: @kgeorgiy i don't think that's correct. i am still learning but according to the javafx documentation this method is to position **The overall alignment of children within the hbox's width and height.** and **NOT** the text inside the button https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html

Comment: @NaorLevi you have been given wrong information. I think ishan has given you the correct answer